# Incremental ingestion of Snowflake data with Delta Live Table (CDC)

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks, delta-live-tables

I have some data which are lying into Snowflake, so I want to apply CDC on them using delta live table but I am having some issues.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
@dlt.view()
def table1():
   return spark.read.format("snowflake").options(**options).option('query', query).load()

dlt.create_streaming_table(target)
dlt.apply_changes(
source = 'table1'
target = 'target'
....
)
```

The same code run well if I am reading a delta table but if its snowflake am having the following error

'org.apache.spark.sql.AalysisException: Source data for the APPLY CHANGES target 'XXXXX' must be a streaming query'

Is there a solution or a workaround you can help me with?

Comment: What SCD Type are you implementing - type 1 or 2?

Comment: I am implementing SCD 2